# Async on_ready syntax error Reason to me is unknown

Tags: python, discord.py

```
async def on_ready()
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

This is the error that is given to me when I try to run the code.

Whole portion of the code is this:

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.client()
TOKEN = 'my token'

@cilent.event
async def on_ready():
     await print("Bot is logged in.")
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you running? `async` was added only in 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
TOKEN = 'my token'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is logged in.")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Also make sure that you're running a version of python that is greater than Python 3.5, as the async statement was added in Python 3.5. You can check your Python version by running this command in a terminal: `python --version`.

Comment: An error on the name of the decorator would have caused a `NameError`, not a `SyntaxError` as in the question.

Comment: It seems as though the code the guy posted is different to the code he ran. If you look at the `SyntaxError` it doesn't have a colon at the end but in the code he provided there is one. So I fixed the other stuff that was either missing or misspelled.